# history.js for parent of iframe

Tags: window, parent, history.js

how can I set the history for the parent window out of an iframe with history.js?

```
window.parent.history.pushState({}, 'Title', 'url');
```

seems to work, but

```
window.parent.History.pushState({}, 'Title', 'url');
```

does not. Can I use `history.js` for this?

Thanks, Andras

Comment: Okay, I found the solution: history.js must be included in the parent html.

Comment: Can you give some more details?  Maybe in an answer to this question?